# Best practice to insert 25k dummy rows into a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to insert around 25k rows into a table by generating autoincrement number. My auto increment number is 19 digits long.

For example,  for one row my query looks like following:

```
insert into myTable(From_Value,To_Value) 
values('6001761093000000000','6001761093999999999');
```

Both my columns are of VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) datatype.

How do write an optimized code for inserting around 25k rows by auto-incrementing `From_Value` and `To_Value`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Santosh.  Do you need `To_Value` to reappear in `From_Value` (are you looking to generate a multi-node graph) or can `From_Value` and `To_Value` be independent?

Comment: Yes,From_Value and To_Value both can be independent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure "best practice" applies to the storing of digits in varchar2 columns but anyway ...

```
insert into myTable(From_Value,To_Value) 
select to_char(6001761093000000000 + (level-1))
      ,to_char(6001761093999999999 + (level-1))
from dual
connect by level <= 25000
```